# How to take a line of string in C

Tags: c

I want to take a line of string in C. How to do that?
if I use format specifier %s in printf, it would only take characters upto first whitespace.How to get rid of it? is there any other way except using getline?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you mean scanf there ?

Comment: @chris: That page also says, "Never use gets()."

Comment: @chris and suggests you use [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead

Comment: @Oren, Yeah, and I didn't see the note about the `_s` version being optional. Seemed like `fgets` with one less argument, but if it's optional, meh. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets

Answer (score 2):

`scanf` is a poor choice for getting lines out of an input stream. While you can do it quite easily:

```
buf[SIZE];
scanf ("%[^\n]\n", buf);
```

You will be at the risk of being subject to a buffer overflow error/attack.

The better way is to read 'SIZE' characters at a time using `fgets`, and copying the data into a dynamically allocated buffer that you can resize upon filling it up:

```
buf[SIZE];
do {
  fgets (buf, SIZE, stdin);
  /* Handle copying to dynamic buffer and resize over here */
} while (/*check we haven't reached eol*/);
```

Comment: "%[^\n]\n" gives the impression that after getting text before the EOL, the EOL (and only the EOL is consumed).  Instead EOL and all the following whitespace is consumed.  Alternative idea "%[^\n]%*c".  But as you suggest `fgets()` is _the_ way to go.